# Vector declaration type in c++

Tags: c++

Please can anybody explain to me what this means?

```
vector<int> myvector(4,99);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`A a(x,y);` creates an object called `a`, calling a constructor of `A` with two parameters matching the types of `x` and `y`, or any convertible types.

So this:

```
vector<int> myvector(4,99);
```

Matches this constructor:

```
explicit vector( size_type num, const TYPE& val = TYPE() ); 
// `TYPE` is a `typedef` assigned to the parametrized type (here `int`), which means the constrcutor is actually:
explicit vector( size_type num, const int& val = int() );
```

Which **constructs a `vector` with 4 elements of value 99 and calls it `myvector`**. This constructor is called because the first parameter can be converted to a `size_type`, which is also a `typedef`, defined to an integral type (usually `unsigned long`).

Answer (score 11):

It's (most likely) an [std::vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/) of integers, initialized to contain four integers with the value of 99.